# Why I get different URL than current active deployment in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I use

```
ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
```

I get following:

[image]

When I look at Manage Deployment and active deployment I get this:

[image]

Why the links are not the same?
Deployed as webapp.

Comment: It's a good question, but what's your use case? Why do you need the URL in the first place?

Comment: According to an existing issue report about [ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() doesn't work for versioned deployments] at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170799249, this is a bug. You may star the issue report to indicate that you're being affected by this issue & to also get email notifications. The issue is still being investigated at the moment. Switching back to the legacy editor [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170799249#comment33] is the current workaround for the issue.